# Digital Signature Use-Non repudiation

Tags: cryptography

if digital signatures alone cannot provide non repudiation and need a third party for that, this means that alone digital signatures are worthless. Am I right..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the protocol and signature  scheme in question whether they provide nonrepudiation without a third party.
For example, in a simple public/private key digital signature setup, the public key is enough for anyone to verify that a given party had the private key to create a digital signature.
The issue then becomes how to provide assurance that the signing party was the only one with access to the private key at the time.

Comment: exactly, hence we need a Certification Authority everytime.

Comment: @prashantgolu: The CA only signs the certificate, not the individual messages. But you can choose to trust a signing key without a CA.

Comment: yes. We can but in order to prove that the sender is repudiating we will need to have a CA.

Comment: @prashantgolu not necessarily, the receiving person may be able to verify that the other party has the private key by other means - he may even have participated when the key was generated in the first place